# Populating object property marked as transient in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a property in my Hibernate entity class which is marked as transient.

Now, without removing `@Transient`, I want to populate that object and I am using `@Formula`.The code is below

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EXCHANGE_VALIDATION_FIELD_LIST")
public class ExchangeValidation {
       
    @Id
    @Column(name = "VALIDATION_FIELD_ID", nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

   @Formula("(select ec from ExchangeCode ec, ExchangeValidation ev where ec.validationFieldId = ev.id")  -- 1)
    @Formula("(select ec from ExchangeCode ec where ec.validationFieldId = id") -- 2)
    @Transient
    public ExchangeCode getExchangeCode() {
    return exchangeCode;
    }

}
```

I tried 1) as well as 2) but still ExchangeCode object is giving null. ExchangeCode is another entity.

What can I try next?

Comment: It should be @ManyToOne mapping instead of formula

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect from the @Transient Annoation?

FYI:
`a method annotated as @Transient, and will be ignored by the entity manager` [Hibernate Manual](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-property)

Remove the annotation and try with a simple query like count the rows first. 
Note that Formula is a native SQL not HQL!